# Refresh access token without user intervention

Tags: android, facebook, refresh, access-token

I am using facebook sdk for android to fetch the FB data. The access_token that is received after successful login expires after a certain time. I want to refresh the token token in the background. ie; the user should nt be prompted for the credentials again.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2):

I hope you can not refresh the access token without the user prompt, becuase it means everybody able to do things without request permission.

If you call the auth process after the access token timedout, it takes just 1 sec, and usualy just a blink on the screen.

Please note that the access token could expire before the expire date. For example the user just logout in another window. Moreover the offline token could expires if the user changes her/his password.

So just call the standard auth url, and your access token will be refreshed.

Comment: What if you want to have a service in the background that periodically  syncs your contacts? You don't want the user to get a dialog while doing something else. You could do a notification but you shouldn't have to.

You can use this in a webservice, why not in an app?

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: Daverix, Facebook changes fast, 1 year ago there wasn't any function like this. :)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can get a token that doesn't expire. Just add `offline_access` to the requested facebook permissions of your app.</strike>

Check the [permissions documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

As pointed out by Kostadin, this way seems to be gone now.

Comment: May 1st 2012 - no more offline access token.